# counting number of speed bumps

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let us consider following problem:

Speed bumps are being placed at $20$ foot intervals along a road $1015$ feet long.  If the first speed bump is placed at one end of the road, how many speed bumps are needed?

(A)  49 (B)  50 (C)  51 (D)  52 (E)  53

if we divide  $1015$ by $20$,we get $50.75$,which means that $50$  speed bumps would be and will be left $15$ feet,because $50*20=1000$,but answer is $51$,why?$50$ is counted  from first speed bump yes?please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a speed bump at one end of the road. If it’s at the beginning, then the speed bumps are at positions $20k$ feet for $k=0,1,\dots,50$, with the last speed bump at $1000$ feet. There are $51$ integers in the set $\{0,1,2,\dots,50\}$ so there are $51$ speed bumps.

If it’s at the end of the road, there’s a speed bump at position $1015-20k$ feet for each $k$ from $0$ through $50$, and there are again $51$ such values of $k$.

It appears that you forgot to count the bump at the end of the road.

Comment: if $k=0$,then bump is located at $1015$?

Comment: @dato: Yes, exactly. That’s the one that your calculation overlooks. And when $k=50$, we have the bump at $15$ feet.

Comment: in other word,bump with number $51$ is  located  at  $1015$ right?then why it is said that they are separated by $20$ feet?

Comment: @dato: Because they are: the distance from any speed bump to an adjacent speed bump is $20$ feet. We could just as well do it the other way around, since they didn’t say at **which** end of the road there’s a speed bump. In fact, it would be easier, and I’ll revise my answer. There’s a speed bump at $20k$ for $k=0,1,\dots,50$, a total of $51$ speed bumps.

Comment: ok thanks very much,just there is  word thing like,first speed bump is placed at one end of the road,what does it mean?

Comment: @dato: Place the road on a coordinate axis running from $0$ at one end to $1015$ at the other. Then it means that the first speed bump is either at $0$ (if we count from left to right) or at $1015$ (if we count from right to left).

Comment: aaaa i see,thanks very much

Comment: @dato: You’re very welcome.